# actionscript 3.0 - increasing counter from a to b in x number of frames

Tags: actionscript, numbers, morphing

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a number fluently change from 'a' to 'b' in 'x' number of frames.

Essentially, I have a bunch of arrow gauges that I will animate to increase or decrease dependant on what is happening in my "simulation".  Alongside these arrows I am having a digital output to indicate precise values.

My inital plan is to have the arrows rotating on a tween and have the numbers change from say' 700 to 750 at the same time over the same time frame.  Without manually changing the numbers within a seperate symbol and having it run same time as the arrows, is there code to do this?

so just to clarify; i want to to make my numbers change from x to y on their own once I decide how many frames the change will take place over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do this with a tweening engine like [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) or [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). You'd just set a variable to hold the number, and add a tween to change it to the target value over the desired amount of time. In the tween's 'update' hook you'd update the text value to be the current value of the variable.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this sounds like what i want to do! 

Is there any example code you could possibly give me (i'm terrible at understanding pseudo code :p)?