# Tweening/scripting a text number count - how to?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a counter that counts from 0 to 250 between two points on the timeline.

Could somebody help me figure out how you might manipulate the dynamic text field to output this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d8d.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my answer here:
[actionscript 3.0 - increasing counter from a to b in x number of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529744/actionscript-3-0-increasing-counter-from-a-to-b-in-x-number-of-frames/17532178#17532178)

> It's pretty easy to do this with a tweening engine like Tweener or
>   TweenLite. You'd just set a variable to hold the number, and add a
>   tween to change it to the target value over the desired amount of
>   time. In the tween's 'update' hook you'd update the text value to be
>   the current value of the variable.